# Facebook API upload photo from URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

I have a website with photo gallery and I'd like to upload each photo (one by one) to my facebook **page** (not wall). I managed to post a message but now I want to upload a photo to a FB Page Wall by uploading an existing image from the server - specific URL (I don't want to upload again locally). Is this possible?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do it
Example
In **[Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=me/photos)**
Make the call post, set url to https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos,
Add field with key `message` and value "any custom message"
Add another field with key `url` and value https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png
click submit

Comment: Almost :) Photos are uploaded but to my personal wall. How can I upload to a Wall on my facebook page (ilija.veselica.photography)? Thanks

Comment: This is the right answer. Photos are uploaded on your personal wall because of /me/photos in the endPoint url. If you want to a specific page, replace /me/ with /pageId/

Comment: Suberb.. Works like a charm. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the album id and make call POST to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/albumid/photos?access_token=$access_token
```

You will find the album id entering into the album and looking at the URL. Will be something like https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.XXXXXXXXXXX.YYYY.ZZZZZZZZZZ&type=3

Your album id are the XXXX.

Comment: This is the album: http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.254503314567659.69923.194544520563539&type=3
So, the album id is 254503314567659. Does this mean that I'm calling https://graph.facebook.com/254503314567659/photos? I proceeded access_token, message and url params and still the same error

Comment: I think it's easier to try to do it here first:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=254503314567659%2Fphotos

Comment: I changed GET to POST and added 2 new parameters: access_token and url.

Comment: Got it! I was using wrong access_token all the time (I used the one for my personal account). In order to get page access token I called: https://graph.facebook.com/ilija.veselica-photography?fields=access_token=XY and it listed tokens from all my pages. XY = my personal account access_token

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
    'fileUpload' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

if($user == 0) {
    // If the user is not connected to your application, redirect the user to authentication page
    /**
     * Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
     * assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
     * JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
     * 
     * The parameters:
     * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
     * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
     */

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,'scope' => PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED));

    echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else {
    // if the user is already connected, then fetch access_token and user's information or show some content to logged in user.
    try
    {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); // Gives you current user's access_token

        $user = $facebook->api('/me'); // Gets User's information based on permissions the user has granted to your application.

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        $results = $e->getResult();
        // Print results if you want to debug.
    }

}

$img = './upload/'.$image_path;
    $args = array(
       'message' => 'Some Message',
        'access_token'=>urlencode($access_token),
    );
    $args[basename($img)] = '@'.realpath($img);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($data,true);
```

Comment: Since you are posting server-side code here, I am assuming "they" is actually "I". In that case, it is wholly inappropriate to actually link to your site in this way, because it is not remotely related to answering this question. But rather than flag this as spam, I am going to edit this answer to be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $config = array('appId' => $config['App_ID'],'secret' => $config['App_Secret']);

            $facebook = new Facebook($config);

            // sets our access token as the access token when we call 
            // something using the SDK, which we are going to do now.
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); 

            $page_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            $page_access_token = "";

            $result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");

            foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
                if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
                    $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
                    break;
                }
            }

            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $photo = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";
            $args = array(
                'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
                'message'       => "message here",
                'url' => $photo,
            );
            $post = $facebook->api("/$page_id/photos","post",$args);
```